# Searching an ArrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I currently have 3 classes, a main class containing a GUI, in which i'm calling this method, a customer class containing the data, and a customerList class which gathers the data from the customer class, puts it into an array list, and also contains the search arraylist method.

I'm trying to implement a search method which can be called from my main class on an action event handler. I'm having a few problems though.

Whenever I run the method, the "                    System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());" line always displays the first familyname in my arraylist.

Don't hesitate to ask for more information, I'm not sure how well i've explained this.

Here is my method:

```
public void searchCustomer(String familyName) {
    int index = 0;
    boolean found = false;
    customer customer;
    while(index < CustomerList.size() && !found) {
        customer = CustomerList.get(index);
        if(customer.returnFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase(familyName)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
        if(found == true) {
            ;
        }
        System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());
        index++;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never increment index.

The code should be:

```
public void searchCustomer(String familyName) {
    for (customer customer : CustomerList) {
        if (customer.returnFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase(familyName)) {
            System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());
            break;
        }
    } 
}
```

Also, the 'customer' class should be called 'Customer' as class names should start with a capital, 'returnFamilyName' should be 'getFamilyName' as accessor methods by convention are named  'get' + the field name and 'CustomerList' should be 'customerList' as field names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you, with regards to renaming my classes and methods I read about that somewhere earlier, and I'll surely be doing it once I finish writing my class.

Comment: Why do you bother with the boolean at this point?  If you've found what you're looking for, you explicitly print it out to the terminal, then break from the enhanced for-loop, and subsequently the entire method.

Comment: @Makoto, thanks. I fixed my code. That mistake got lost in all the other problems with the original code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your question what the intended behaivor actually *is*.  Besides that, what is this ?

```
if (found == true);
```

Presumably you meant :

```
if (found) { 
    System.out.println...
}
```

But what if the same last name occurs twice in your list?  Also why aren't using a `Map` instead of a `List`?  Lookup will go from being `O(n)` to `O(1)`

Answer (score 2):

Drop the `;` in `if (found == true);` because that reads as: `if this condition is true, do notihng` and use braces always:

```
if (found == true) {
   System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());
}
```

Also, include the increment inside the `while` loop, otherwise you are not really iterating anything.

This code seems to work because your first element happens to coincide with the searched element, try with a different one and you'll end up in a infinite loop.

Try with a version like this:

```
public void searchCustomer( String familyName ) {

    for ( customer current : CustomerList ) {           
        if ( current.returnFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase( familyName )) {
            System.out.println( current.returnFamilyName() );
            break;
        }
     }
}
```

Some additional remarks:

In Java clases should start with uppercase, so the class name should be declared as `Customer` instead of `customer` and variables start with lowercase, hence `CustomerList` should be `customerList`. Methods may avoid the `return` part and be named with a `get`

Also, search methods should better return the found value instead of printing it, so your final version could look like this:

```
public Customer searchCustomer( String familyName ) {
    for ( Customer current : customerList ) {
       if ( current.getFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase( familyName ) )  {
          return current;
       }
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest try this:

```
System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());
                index++;
if(found == true) { return;}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to increment the `while` loop or it has the potential to run indefinitely.

You can elect to use what is known as an ["enhanced for-loop"](http://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with), which allows you to eschew the need to increment values over `CustomerList` entirely.  You have an object `customer`, so we can use that as follows:

```
for (customer cus: CustomerList) {
     if(cus.returnFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase(familyName)) {
        System.out.println(cus.returnFamilyName());
        return;
     }
}
```

If you elect to stick with your original code (which is fine), then observe the changes in your code below.

```
while(index < CustomerList.size()) {
    customer = CustomerList.get(index);
    if (customer.returnFamilyName().equalsIgnoreCase(familyName)) { 
        System.out.println(customer.returnFamilyName());
        break;
    } else {  
        index++;
    }
}
```